# Quantitative Aptitude Problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

[image]

I am confused by the calculation of Nicholas' birth year. What I did was writing $N$ as

$N = 25x + 2$

$N = 21y + 3$

$N = 23z + 6$

Just trying integer values, I couldn't even get close to the answer. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the quantitative reasoning exam this is from?

Comment: It was asked in a practice test held in my coaching institute where I am preparing for GATE (Graduate Aptitude Test in Engineering).

Comment: 3227 must be wrong, since it doesn't leave a remainder 3 when you divide by 21. It's not a multiple of 3, so it can't leave such a remainder on division by a multiple of 3.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson for pointing that out. I was able to solve it after seeing your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood the question before. The question says that

Nicholas Birth year = 25*x + 2 ..... (1)

x = 21*y + 3 ..... (2)

y = 23*z + 6 ..... (3)

Nicholas Birth year = 25 * [ 21 * { 23*z + 6} + 3 ] + 2 = 12075z + 3227

Taking z=0

Nicholas Birth year = 3227